# Rotating Words with jQuery Animations

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to create a typography effect and want to rotate a part of sentence. I have tried using  jQuery animations.

I want to animate word up.
Here is my code

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  $("#tchange").animate({
    "top": "-=15px"
  }, 100).fadeOut("fast");
  $('#tchange').text("Xyz").css('top', '-10px').slideDown("slow");
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">
        Get on the Current Release.<br>
        Boost your 
        <span id="tchange">
            Competitiveness
        </span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ ? Also show us how exactly you want to animate your word If any demo ?

Comment: I want to animate word same like http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3RotatingWords/ but want to animate up rather than down and not want fade in effect

Comment: This is just example but text coming from database so

Comment: @Bhumi, See this: http://jsfiddle.net/5uzpe/2/

Comment: Thanks for reply and I have tried this  but i dont want fade in/out effect when text animate

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not support CSS3 animating. You'll need to either animate purely with CSS, use jQuery to swap CSS classes causing the CSS animation effect or quickly increment the inline CSS3 animation property on the element (like how animating in jQuery actually works).

Eg.

```
var x=0, timer=1; //Change timer to change FPS

setInterval(function() { 
    x++;
    $('#myelement').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + x + ')'); 
}, timer);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but its not works because what about text.?

Comment: @Bhumi Add your text to an element like <div id="myelement">This is some text</div> then animate that element.

Comment: for example,i have text like,so its not wotking with your code
<div id="myelement">This is some text</div><div id="myelement">This is other text</div> <div id="myelement">This is new text</div>

Answer (score 0):

One good way is by using css:
by changing `opacity` and `rotate` properties.

```css
.rw-words {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
.rw-words-1 span {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #6b969d;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  color: #6b889d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
  color: #6b739d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  -o-animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
  color: #7a6b9d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
  color: #8d6b9d;
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(275deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Get on the Current Eagle Release.<br>Boost your<div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
      <span>Competitiveness</span>
      <span>abc</span>
      <span>def</span>
      <span>ghi</span>
      <span>jkl</span>
     </div>
    
    </h1>
```

but, ofcourse you can use jQuery too (but it wil use more memory):

```js
var degrees = 0,
  timer = 1; //Change timer to change FPS

setInterval(function() {
  if (degrees < 359) {
    degrees++;
  } else {
    degrees = 0;
  }

  $('.rw-words-1 span').css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'); //.css('opacity',degrees/359+'');

}, timer);
```

```css
.rw-words {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
.rw-words-1 span {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #6b969d;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  color: #6b889d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
  color: #6b739d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  -o-animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
  color: #7a6b9d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
  color: #8d6b9d;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Get on the Current Eagle Release.<br>Boost your<div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
      <span>Competitiveness</span>
      <span>abc</span>
      <span>def</span>
      <span>ghi</span>
      <span>jkl</span>
     </div>
    
    </h1>
```